# How many tables is acceptable in a Database?

Tags: database, database-design

I am currently designing a database for a file sharing service. Every folder that is created on this service will have its own Table(Folder_) each Folder will also be added to a Table which will have the folders and their owners.

Is this bad practice? The reason being I have there are several features which I want to incorporate into this service which require me to have a table for each folder i.e permissions/different levels of access.

e.g The owner of Folder A has added 3 users with different levels of access to the folder User1, User2, User3.

User1 has view only access.

User2 has edit access.

User3 has full access.

The reason I can't see another of doing it except for creating a table for each folder is, if I had a Table of File/Folders with the usual attributes where could I put the users who have access to the folder and their level of permission? Also how would User1 view what folders they have access to with a big search of the entire database etc

The reason I dont think it can be good practice, is the amount of tables that will be in the database?

Comment: Before the question gets closed as opinion based, I'd suggest you to draw the ER diagram... You will be able to finalize the tables better.

Comment: you're using 1 table per folder just to avoid having a permissions table?

Comment: Folders--<Folder_Permissions>--Permissions--<User_Permissions--<User ties back to folders folder has a user user can have many folders.

Comment: The need to change the database schema as part of an application's normal operation is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). You should (pretty much) never want/need to do this.

Comment: Answering the question in the title, I think that after 1 trillion tables, a database gets somewhat unwieldy.

Comment: as an extension of @Alex's comment: if the application gets hacked then the attacker gets to take advantage of whatever permissions the application's database user has. so if your database user has permissions to execute ddl, the attacker gets to do that too. You can't lock down the database user permissions with this approach.

Comment: @NathanHughes so if I implement a solution similar to the one down below that I have accepted as the correct answer, will that solution prevent this from hapening

Comment: right, JSR's approach means the application doesn't need to execute ddl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a single table for folders, another table for users and a third table for user folder permissions.  If you are making many tables that all have the same columns, you are probably not normalizing correctly.

```
Table: Folders
    FolderId
    FolderName
    OwnerUserId     -- references Users table to identify the owner
    (additional columns as necessary to describe a single folder)

Table: Users
    UserId
    UserName
    (additional columns as necessary to describe a single user)

Table: FolderUsers
    FolderId    -- references Folders table
    UserId      -- references Users table
    Permission  -- (ViewOnly, Edit, Full, etc)
```

The FolderUsers table is called a junction table, it allows a many-to-many relationship between Folders and Users, just add a row for each folder/user combination.